# Adding fields dynamically to Share form

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to add a text field for each file that is added to the attached package items in alfresco to write notes regarding each file, is it possible to do?

Comment: do you need to use these fields to update the metadata of the attached documents or to just set a property on the task ? is the container a workflow task or another document/folder ?

Comment: I need those fields to set properties of the task, the container is a workflow task 
the scenario is that when  a use adds files to the workflows package Items, he can also add notes about each file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented something that could be reused for your use case.

You can define a property with multiple values that will contain the list of notes associated with each attachment.

There is a simple trick to post a property with multiple values: add "[]" to the name of the property. For example:

```
<input id="template_x002e_edit-metadata_x002e_edit-metadata_x0023_default_prop_someco_notes_0" 
    name="prop_someco_notes[]" 
    tabindex="0" 
    type="text" 
    value="Meeting minutes" 
    title="Notes"
    noderef="workflow://...."
    >

<input id="template_x002e_edit-metadata_x002e_edit-metadata_x0023_default_prop_someco_notes_1" 
    name="prop_someco_notes[]" 
    tabindex="1" 
    type="text" 
    value="Meeting minutes" 
    title="Notes"
    noderef="workflow://...."
>
```

As you can see, the name of the input ends with []. Both input textfields have the same name.

The Alfresco Form Engine will consider these two inputs as the value for the property with multiple values: "someco:notes".

The bigger problem is that you need to generate this html with some smart javascript and free marker template.

You can write a custom free marker template to render the initial html: if a user opens a task on which documents have been already attached, you will need to generate the list of inputs using a custom control (you can of course start from textfield.ftl).

It won't be easy to generate the initial list because unfortunately Alfresco returns the list of values as a single comma separated value.

You can customise the webscript that injects the model in the free marker template "org.alfresco.web.scripts.forms.FormUIGet" to pass an array instead of a csv.

A quicker and dirtier solution is to split the csv value. In share-config-custom.xml, you can specify what textfield.ftl show use as a separator instead of the comma.

When a user adds/remove elements from the package, you can intercept the update and add/remove the correspondent note. Notice that I have added the filed "noderef" to each input so it is possible to know the relation between the notes and the nodes in the package.

**UPDATE:**
For the associations (used for example to define the package in a workflow task), Share uses a javascript library called "object finder" (or "object picker"). This library fires an event called "formValueChanged" that you can intercept:

```
        YAHOO.Bubbling.fire("formValueChanged",
        {
           eventGroup: this,
           addedItems: addedItems,
           removedItems: removedItems,
           selectedItems: selectedItems,
           selectedItemsMetaData: Alfresco.util.deepCopy(this.selectedItems)
        });
```

Comment: thanks for answer, in fact I'm still a beginner in alfresco and I can use any clarification possible, what is the code segment you posted? where should I try with similar logic ?

Comment: I copied the code segment from a form opened by share. If you open a form, for example with "Edit Properties" or you open a task in "edit mode", you can see the same type of html. This html is generated by the "Alfresco Form Engine" that is based on Alfresco webscripts. All the OOTB templates are in the folder: "share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/". You can find there, for example the template "controls/textfield.ftl" that is used by Share for textfield properties.

Comment: In share-config-custom.xml, you can configure the forms and specify which template to use for each property. If you do not specify a template, Share will use a default one based on the type of property.

Comment: very helpful !! thanks alot, but how to intercept the update in alfresco ? I failed to find any related listeners in alfresco

Comment: is there anyway I can use the noderef filed in the task listeners?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just misunderstood a part of your answer. I applied the solution you suggested, but now I'm getting a 'Property values must be of a Serializable type! Value type: class org.json.JSONArray' error when I complete or save the task

Comment: I see. In what class? Could you attach part of the stacktrace?

Comment: The error isn't related to a class I've written,I haven't yet written any java class related to this workflow, this error is shown in a dialogue in alfresco share, 'org.alfresco.repo.forms.FormException: 01090013 Property values must be of a Serializable type! Value type: class org.json.JSONArray'

Comment: I figured out the problem, I forgot to add the multiple tag to the related property in the model.